# What is the best way to create a "fully" modular ZF-based application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, modularity

For the past time I have been working on a Zend Framework based webshop application that we are building from scratch. The application has been successfully been set up for several clients, but we are stumbling upon more and more problems regarding extensibility and modularity of the application.

A lot of clients require a lot of different approaches on some matters, often requiring customizing default modules or extending them. I have been looking on the web for Zend Framework based code that could guide me to this and so far [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com) has been the only example I have come up with. Although Magento seems to do a very good job offering extensibility and modularity, the code is far too complex and extensive for my current needs (or so it seems).

**In an ideal situation, it would work as follows:**

- Each client gets the "base" application installed
- Modules, controllers, models should be easily overridden or extended
- New modules should be easily created

Are there any other Zend Framework based applications or other pointers that could guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No offense, but this is a "tell me how to be a better programmer" type of question. The answer is going to be deep and complex, and driven by the principles of OOD - primarily polymorphism. Unless you are just looking for a ZF-based project to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Peter; I don't take any offense, but I am not sure what your point is. If you are saying that the answer might be too complex for me to grasp: this could be so. But we are all here to learn and I admit I could use some pointers as I am pretty much lost at this point.

Comment: I'm just saying that this is the type of thing that programmers learn over the course of months and it will take an individual far smarter than myself to give you a useful answer here in the limited context of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand your point. As said, I still hope to find some pointers in this "limited context", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think version 1.8 of the Zend Framework is going to address a lot of the issues with building modular applications. Especially with the new ([Zend_Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.html)) it should allow for auto loading of module resources, which isn't easy to do at this point.

I don't know much about it, but this may be something to look into. 1.8 should be out by the end of this month.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework is a... framework.  What you're looking for is a full blown system.  That's your job as a developer is to build a system on top of a framework (whether Zend or your own).

People usually tell you not to reinvent the wheel, but in this case you need to develop your own system for your company to easily be able to develop and deploy for new clients.

Like already stated, it is a very complex answer you are looking for.  You will not get that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. I do want to make clear however that I am not looking for a "copy / paste" solution that I can use. I am very interested in the solutions others have possibly thought of encountering this problems, since I haven't thought of one so far.

Comment: Others don't know the full requirements of what you really need.  Sure you listed basic requirements, but that's way too vague.  Anything more complicated and you're basically asking for a consultation, which people normally get paid really good money for.